# IDEA break fromat when introduce local variable

Tags: intellij-idea, refactoring

I am trying to introduce local variable and IDEA breaks my formatting, what i doing wrong?
[image]
I have tried cntrl+enter at end of line and cntrl+alt+v.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `settings->Editor->Code style->Java-> Wrapping and braces` at the Keep when formatting section enable line breaks.